# Get post format and use it as a CSS class in different spans

Tags: css, html, post-formats, get-post

I use a `<span>` inside the loop and I would like to get each post format the post is containing as a class in separate `spans`.

Example:

**If** the post format **is video and private**: I would like to render:

```
<span class="format-video"></span>
<span class="status-private"></span>
```

So far I have tried `<span <?php get_post_format_string($class); ?>></span>` which did not work for me because this will render all the post formats and status in one `span`, not in different `spans`...

Comment: How did you add the post format 'private'?

Answer (score 1):

You can also try `<span class="<?php echo get_post_format($post->ID); ?>"></span>`
Additional details available [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_format)

Edited from here:

Well according to the link I provided, get_post_format() give you the post format post the post_type post.

So if you want to use it in loop, you could try

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
   echo '<span class="'.get_post_format().'">Your content</span>';   
endwhile;
```

The above code will output a class in you're `span` based on the post format. For instance, if you're post is an image format the output will be like

```
<span class="image">You're content</span>
```

I hope this make sense

Comment: Please elaborate...

Answer (score 1):

Every post has a maximum of one format and one status. To echo the format you need:

```
if (get_post_format($post->ID))
    echo '<span class="format-' . get_post_format($post->ID); . '"></span>';
```

To echo the status you need this:

```
if (get_post_status($post->ID))
    echo '<span class="status-' . get_post_status($post->ID); . '"></span>';
```

Hopefully this is what you need.

Comment: Where should I place this code? I need to add the code outside `<?php the_content`

Comment: In the same place where your non working code is...